# PHP looping through an array to fetch a value for each key from database (third normal form)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am building a system, mostly for consolidating learning but will be used in practice.

I will try and verbally explain the part of the E-R diagram I am focusing on:

Each cadet can have many uniformID's

Each Uniform ID is a new entry in table uniform, so `cadets` (table) may look like:

```
id | name    | ... | uniformID

1  | Example | ... | 1,2,3
```

`uniform` table:

```
id | notes             | cadet

1  | Need new blahh    | 1

2  | Some stuff needed | 1

3  | Whatever you like | 1
```

On second thought, looks like I wont need that third column in the db.

I am trying to iterate through each id in uniformID, code:

```
<?php
$cadet = $_GET['id']; // set  from URL

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `uniformID` FROM `cadets` 
  WHERE id = '$cadet' LIMIT 1") 
  or die(mysql_error()); // get uniform needed as string

// store it
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $uniformArray = $row['uniformID']; 
}
echo $uniformArray . "  ";
$exploded = explode(",", $uniformArray); // convert into an array

// for each key in the array perform a new query
foreach ($exploded as $key => $value) {
  $query(count($exploded));
  $query[$key] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `uniform` WHERE `id` = '$value'");
}
```

?>

As I say, this is mainly for consolidation purposes but I have come up with a error, sql is saying:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\wamp\www\intranet\uniform.php on line 82

line 82 is:

```
$query[$key] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `uniform` WHERE `id` = '$value'");
```

I wasn't sure it would work so I tried it and now i'm stuck!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to everyone who has contributed to this! This is now the working code:

```
foreach ($exploded as $key => $value) {
              //$query(count($exploded));
              $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `uniform` WHERE `id` = '$value'");
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo "<tr>
                  <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['note'] . "</td>
                </tr>";
              }
            }
```

Added the while and did the iteration by nesting it in the foreach

Comment: You have weird quotes around uniform and id, is that a coincidence?

Comment: Nope, syntactically i'm sure; they should be there, `` demarks a database field / name (I think), use it everywhere else in my code without problem - I wouldn't imagine these are throwing the error

Comment: The error is here `$query(count($exploded));`. Line 81.

Comment: I see, I was trying to declare the variable as an array of that length, is there a better way of doing so?

Comment: A good way to find an sql error is to echo your generated query. Ofter there are wrong quotes.

Comment: @Liam - those "weird quotes" are very much standard backticks that can be used around table and column names in MySQL

Comment: There is no need to specify the size of an array beforehand in php.

Comment: what about `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `uniform` WHERE `cadet` = '$cadet'");`?

Comment: @air4x throwing this now, Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\wamp\www\intranet\uniform.php on line 86

Comment: maybe you got a "gremlin" (an invisibile, unwanted, non printable character) near the actual "mysql_query" string

Comment: At the top you have assigned the result of `mysql_query`, which is a resource, to `$query`. Rename that variable.

Comment: Can you hold a result of `mysql_query` in an array? Check by just trying to set `$query` rather than `$query[$key]`.
And note, you should be sanitising your data inputs. `$cadet=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);`

Comment: `mysql_query` will only return a resource. You will have to fetch the results with `mysql_fetch_*` functions using this resource.

Comment: @npfedwards using  $query = does not throw an error, but I am still in the same place as I am just after the explode

Comment: @air4x Good point. PHP's typing is usually so silent we forget about it.

Comment: I have sorted it thanks to those of you who contributed answers, I think everyone here has helped sort the errors out, plus I have learned a new concept in programming :) I will write up an answer when it lets me for others in the same situation, or if someone else wants too I changed the foreach loop's operation, new code bottom of OP

Comment: @npfedwards can I just ask sorry what is php typing?

Comment: @zomboble to be honest, I don't know much about it. Here's the docs http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php.
In many other languages like C you have to state what type of variable something is `Int`, `String`, `Array` etc. But php isn't strict when it comes to typing. However, you'd already made `$query` a string so when you then tried to add array entries to it I think php threw a fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your tables

```
cadets(id, ...)
uniforms(id, ...)
```

use a cross-product table that describes the relation between entities of `cadets` and entities of `uniforms`

```
cadets_x_uniforms(cadet_id, uniform_id)
```

For each relationship (in this case cadet x has uniform y) put a record with the respective ids into the cross-product table.

... hm, a working example will do better in this case I suppose...

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
setup($pdo);

// fetch the uniforms of a specific cadet
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT
        c.name,u.id,u.labelid
    FROM
        so_cadets as c
    LEFT JOIN
        so_cadet_uniform as cxu
    ON
        c.id=cxu.cadet_id
    LEFT JOIN
        so_uniforms as u
    ON
        cxu.uniform_id=u.id
    WHERE
        c.name=?
');
$stmt->execute( array('cadetB') );
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "uniforms of cadetB\n";
foreach( $stmt as $row ){
    echo join(', ', $row), "\n";
}

// fetch cadets without uniforms
$query = '
    SELECT
        c.name
    FROM
        so_cadets as c
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS(SELECT uniform_id FROM so_cadet_uniform as cxu WHERE c.id=cxu.cadet_id)
';
echo "cadets without uniforms\n";
foreach( $pdo->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ){
    echo join(', ', $row), "\n";
}   


function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE so_cadets (
            id int auto_increment,
            name varchar(32),
            primary key(id)
        )
    ');

    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE so_uniforms (
            id int auto_increment,
            labelid varchar(32),
            primary key(id),
            unique key(labelid)
        )
    ');

    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE so_cadet_uniform (
            cadet_id int,
            uniform_id int,
            primary key(cadet_id,uniform_id)
        )
    ');


    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO so_cadets (name) VALUES (?)');
    foreach( range('A','F') as $c ) {
        $stmt->execute( array('cadet'.$c));
    }

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO so_uniforms (labelid) VALUES (?)');
    foreach( range('K','Z') as $c ) {
        $stmt->execute( array('label'.$c));
    }

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO so_cadet_uniform (cadet_id,uniform_id) VALUES (?,?)');
    $cadetHasUniforms = array(
        1=>array(1,2,3), // <- cadetA
        2=>array(7,9), // <- cadetB
        3=>array(8,5,4), // <- cadetC
        // 4=>array() <- cadetD, no entry, no uniforms
        5=>array(10,13,15) // <- cadetE
        // <- cadetE, no entry, no uniforms
    );
    foreach( $cadetHasUniforms as $cadetId=>$uniformIds ) {
        foreach( $uniformIds as $uid ) {
            $stmt->execute(array($cadetId, $uid));
        }
    }

}
```

prints

```
uniforms of cadetB
cadetB, 7, labelQ
cadetB, 9, labelS
cadets without uniforms
cadetD
cadetF
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! I need to look into the PDO, this looks like a good excuse for me to do it! I will mark this as accepted (as it has worked around the problem) and is a fantastic answer!